# How to fix HTTP ERROR 500 cpanel - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, http-status-code-500

I am trying to deploy a Laravel application on a shared hosting but I am getting HTTP ERROR 500 when I try to access the web in the browser.

I have configured my index.php file, and my php version is 5.6.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is my error log:

```html
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/umugeoyw/umugabo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500
```

and on line 500 in helpers.php I have this:

```html
return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null);
```

Comment: HTTP status code 500 means server error, you should try debugging your php code.

Comment: My app runs perfectly on a local server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the PHP Version. Laravel is using a Null coalescing operator here (??). Since this feature is only available on PHP 7.0 and later, your server will squark.

In your DevEnv you probably do have PHP 7.0 +.

You can checkout the [docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). From the docs:

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

PHP 5.6 is outdated anyways, so you really should consider updating! Btw.: Laravel requires PHP 7.1.3, which is clearly stated in their [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#server-requirements):

> ```
> PHP >= 7.1.3
> OpenSSL PHP Extension
> PDO PHP Extension
> Mbstring PHP Extension
> Tokenizer PHP Extension
> XML PHP Extension
> Ctype PHP Extension
> JSON PHP Extension
> ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As [errorinpersona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10462490/errorinpersona) described, you should change php version of your server from cpanel settings and match it with the version on your local server, and you should be good.